# Determine If Users Are In Active Directory With PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to determine which user folders in C:\Users have active users in Active Directory.

I currently have the following:

```
$userProfile = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users"
$unknownList = @()
foreach($user in $userProfile){
    try{
        Get-ADUser -Identity $user.Name | Out-Null
    }
    catch{
        $unknownList += $user.Name
    }
}
Write-Host $unknownList
```

My issue is that all usernames appear to not exist and are caught.  Can anyone offer some suggestions for a PowerShell first-timer?  I have a tried a number of other things found here and elsewhere but none have been able to work.  Thank you!

Comment: The name of the folder in `C:\Users` does not nesessarly match the name of the user in AD. It could be `username.DomainName.###` if the user profile already existed.

Comment: Your code looks correct, as far as I can tell. The only thing that might be an issue is that your `Catch { }` block might never be reached, because Get-ADUser creates non-terminating errors. To work around this, use `-ErrorAction Stop` on `Get-ADUser`. That changes errors into terminating errors.

Comment: @TrevorSullivan His problem is that *all* names throw an error and thus end up in `$unknownList`.

Comment: What are the actual errors that cause the names to end up in `$unknownList`? Add a line `Write-Error $_` to the `catch` block so you can see what's going on. Are you using PowerShell v2? PowerShell didn't support automatic module loading before v3, so you'd need to run `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` before you could use `Get-ADUser`. You can check your PowerShell version by echoing `$PSVersionTable`.

Comment: I'd use Get-ACL on the ntuser.dat file in each folder and see if the Owner resolved to a user, or was an orphan SID. Using the folder name for account resolution may not be reliable.  User names can be changed or truncated and not match the name of their home folder.

Comment: @mjolinor That's unreliable as well. If the user is a member of the Administrators group or an administrator changed the default permissions on the profile, so that administrators and SYSTEM have access to it, the owner of the file won't be the user to whom the profile belongs.

Comment: Agreed. But I don't know of any method that bad practice can't render unreliable to some degree.

Comment: I consider it good practice to grant administrators and SYSTEM access to user profiles. The default of giving just the owner access to a profile only makes troubleshooting harder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was wanting to do something similar, and was appalled that it seemed like the only way to see if a user exists in AD was to barbarically have the Get-ADUser throw an error, and you then catch it. After much research, I found that instead of using the `-Identity` parameter if you use the `-Filter` parameter you actually get back, either the user object(s) that match the filter parameter, or a $Null object (because nothing matches the `-Filter` parameter). Once you have that in a variable, you can then do a "proper" if/else statement evaluation without throwing any errors.

Here is your code:

```
$userProfile = Get-ChildItem #-Path "C:\Users"
$unknownList = @()
foreach($user in $userProfile){

    #Try getting the user
    $ADUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -eq $User.Name}

    #Test to see if the user exists
    If($ADUser)
    {
        #User Exists
        #Write-host "$($User.Name) Exists"
    }
    Else
    {
        #User does not Exist
        #Write-host "$($User.Name) Does not Exist"

        Write-host "$($User.Name)"
    }
}
```