# Updating Active Directory Field from Csv

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

Giving myself a fun little project today I thought, but now it's grown into an issue and the solution eludes me. I have a massive .Csv file with all our employees `sAMAccountName` and `telephoneNumber` attributes. I would like to update all of the telephone numbers in our active directory. I was poking around some of my old scripts, taking parts and pieces that would work for this my first iteration got me too here.

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Results\EmployeeExtsTest.csv

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    $User = $User.sAMAccountName
    $telephoneNumber = $User.telephoneNumber
    Get-ADUser -Identity $User | Set-ADUser -telephoneNumber $telephoneNumber
    }
```

That's when I discovered that PowerShell doesn't have a `-telephoneNumber` attribute. So I did some digging and then arrived here.

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Results\EmployeeExtsTest.csv

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    $User = $User.sAMAccountName
    $telephoneNumber = $User.telephoneNumber
    Get-ADUser -Identity $User | Set-ADUser -Add @{telephoneNumber=$telephoneNumber}
    }
```

I tested it out with my user at first and I keep getting the following.

```
Set-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Add'. The argument is null or an element of the argument collection contains a null value.
At line:6 char:50
+ ... -Identity $User | Set-ADUser -Add @{telephoneNumber=$telephoneNumber}
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

I know that it's reading my .Csv correctly because I can call it just fine. It outputs the following.

```
sAMAccountName telephoneNumber
-------------- ---------------
zgroven        1121
```

I know this solution "should" be easy but it's completely escaping me!

Comment: If you remove get and set ad user and leave just `@{telephoneNumber=$telephoneNumber}` do you see right information coming out of your loop? Also note, if the user already has the attribute set, you will want to use -Replace instead of -Add

Comment: That's good for me to know about -Add and -Replace, but for this test I've gone in an deleted my telephoneNumber field to make sure it all come through.
I've hashed out the last line and called $User and $telephoneNumber seperately. I get the correct return for $User, but nothing back for $telephoneNumber. curious.

Comment: Are you sure your CSv is comma delimited ? Other than that my guess is you have a typo somewhere

Comment: I'm absolutely sure of that. it outputs just fine when I call it. I've just added a second `sAMAccountName` and `telephoneNumber` to the .Csv and called it to test.
`sAMAccountName telephoneNumber
-------------- ---------------
zgroven        1121           
dtolman        1132 `

Comment: SEt-Aduser is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps).  There are parameters such as -HomePhone, -Officephone, and -MobilePhone.  Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are being misled by what is displayed and what the actual name of the property is, due to behind-the-scenes aliasing.

Try using this instead:

```
set-aduser $user -OfficePhone $telephoneNumber
```

Comment: Edited the script to this.
`$Users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Results\EmployeeExtsTest.csv

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    $User = $User.sAMAccountName
    $telephoneNumber = $User.telephoneNumber
    Set-ADUser $User -OfficePhone $telephoneNumber
    }`
The script completed, but no attributes were changed. For some reason its not reading the telephoneNumber feild in my .Csv

Comment: `telephoneNumber` is a real ldap attribute. What OP is doing looks correct

Comment: I think it works! I will test with multiple lines now in the .Csv using a few test accounts to make sure. I think it was a combination of looking for attributes that were not there and me getting my variables crossed up. I'll post the working script below.

Comment: `$Users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Results\EmployeeExtsTest.csv

ForEach ($U in $Users) {
    $User = $U.sAMAccountName
    $telephoneNumber = $U.telephoneNumber
    Set-ADUser $User -OfficePhone $telephoneNumber
    }`

Comment: It still is not working for multiple users, just 1 at a time, but its still further than i've been before. Adding `-WhatIf` on the end shows that its pulling both accounts and performing the operation "Set" on the targets, but no data is changing.

Comment: User a write-host in the loop to make sure that the set-aduser $user command looks right during each itteration: Write-host Set-ADUser $User -OfficePhone $telephoneNumber

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @PaulWain answer. Active Directory Users and Computers displays `Telephone Number`, the AD Attribute is `telephoneNumber`, but `Set-ADUser` oddly uses the parameter `OfficePhone` for setting it. Another quirk due to `OfficePhone` being a "special" field, when clearing with `Set-ADUser` you actually have to use `telephoneNumber` as the field. e.g.:

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Results\EmployeeExtsTest.csv
  
ForEach ($UserEntry in $Users) {
  $User = Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -like '$($UserEntry.sAMAccountName)'" -Properties *

  #Check to see if the user exists
  if($User)
  {
    #Check to see if the Office Phone number has been cleared in CSV
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($UserEntry.telephoneNumber))
    {
      #Clear the user's OfficePhone (telephoneNumber) in Active Directory
      Set-ADUser -Identity $User -Clear telephoneNumber
    }
    else
    {                                               
      #Update the user in Active Directory
      Set-ADUser -Identity $User -OfficePhone $UserEntry.telephoneNumber
    }
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Host "User $($UserEntry.sAMAccountName) does not exist in Active Directory"
  }
}
```

One thing I add to my script is to use the `-Filter` parameter on my `Get-ADUser` that way I can verify the user exists without `Get-ADUser` throwing an error. See my answer for more information ["Determine If Users Are In Active Directory With PowerShell"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21057295/2150063):

The other method is to modify all of the properties all at once, and then use the `Set-ADUser -Instance` parameter to set them all at once (note: OfficePhone/telephoneNumber are special and have to be cleared manually like the above code, other fields can be manually cleared/set blank):

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Results\EmployeeExtsTest.csv

ForEach ($UserEntry in $Users) {
  $User = Get-ADUser -Filter "samAccountName -like '$($UserEntry.sAMAccountName)'" -Properties *

  #Check to see if the user exists
  if($User)
  {
    #Check to see if the Office Phone number has been cleared in CSV
    if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($UserEntry.telephoneNumber))
    {
      #Clear the user's OfficePhone (telephoneNumber) in Active Directory
      Set-ADUser -Identity $User -Clear telephoneNumber
    }
    else
    {                                               
      #Modify Local instance of the user's properties
      $User.OfficePhone = $UserEntry.telephoneNumber
    }

    #Modify Local instance of other user's properties
    $User.GivenName = $UserEntry.GivenName
    $User.Surname = $UserEntry.Surname

    #..... etc.....

    #Update the user in Active Directory
    Set-ADUser -Instance $User
  }
  else
  {
    Write-Host "User $($UserEntry.sAMAccountName) does not exist in Active Directory"
  }
}
```

Comment: Really good info here! I really appreciate the piece-by-piece approach! I will be incorporating this into the final version!

Comment: @NorwegiaMan, For a final version, I would use the other method `Set-ADUser` which is to modify all of the properties all at once on the AD User object, and then use the `Set-ADUser -Instance` parameter to set them all at once. See edits above.

Answer (score 0):

The final script that got me through this is here

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Results\EmployeeExts.csv

ForEach ($U in $Users) {
    $User = $U.sAMAccountName
    $telephoneNumber = $U.telephoneNumber
    Set-ADUser $User -OfficePhone $telephoneNumber
    }
```

Because I work for a school district I will be adding on more to this in the future to look for employees that are missing. As it stands now this script just updated nearly 1000 AD accounts perfectly (aside from the missing employees that have left). I want to thank all of you for helping in giving me pieces of this answer. You've made me better at my job.

Special thanks to @PaulWain and @HAL9256

Comment: Im surprised that using an add hash didn't work for you. I couldn't repro on my lab.